# Adicionar mais de uma chave idêntica em uma tabela

Tags: java, lista, hashmap

Surgiu um problema em um trecho do código, onde é armazenado em uma variavel HashMap 2 valores distintos, o problema é que a indexação pelo que entendi é feito pela chave, ou seja, não é possivel ter chave duplicada. Segue o trecho do código em questão:

```
HashMap contribuinteList = (HashMap) origem.get("ConstribuinteList");

idContribuinte = request.getParameter("idcontribuinte");
exercicio = gb.getYear();

contribuinteList.put(idContribuinte, exercicio);
```

Qual seria a melhor forma de trabalhar nessa situação, tendo em vista que posso ter mais de 1 contribuinte ?

Comment: Não entendi o problema. Se pode ter mais de um contribuinte, entendo que cada um tem um ID diferente, então é só adicionar no map: `contribuinteList.put(idContribuinte1, exercicio1)`, `contribuinteList.put(idContribuinte2, exercicio2)`, etc. Eu só mudaria o nome para `contribuintes`, ou `contribuinteMap`, já que `contribuinteList` pode dar a falsa impressão de que se trata de uma lista (`List`, `ArrayList`, etc), que é outra estrutura de dados completamente diferente

Comment: Amigo @Victor Henrique cada contribuinte vai ter seu próprio id, então não é para ter chave duplicada....

Comment: É uma importação, logo eu posso ter "15336,2018" , "15336,2019", o id pode se repetir. Nesse caso ele atualizaria a chave, o que nao poderia ocorrer, ja que preciso da integridade dos dados conforme foram inseridos.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
List listaContribuinte = new ArrayList();

HashMap map = new HashMap();

map.put(IdContribuinte,exercicio);

listaContribuinte.add(map);

for( int i = 0; i < listaContribuinte.size(); i++){
   // Percorro linha a linha da lista pegando o map para realizar as ações.
}
```